# What are all the available hosted agent pools for Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

On Azure Pipelines of Azure DevOps you can use [Microsoft hosted agent pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=vsts&tabs=yaml) to run your pipelines. You define those as `job.pool.vmImage` in your `azure-pipeline.yml`.

Unfortunately, the docs currently only seems to list a few of the available agent pools on the [list of Microsoft hosted agent pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=vsts&tabs=yaml):

> The Microsoft-hosted agent pool provides 5 virtual machine images to
>   choose from:
>
> - Ubuntu 16.04 (`ubuntu-16.04`)
> - Visual Studio 2017 on Windows Server 2016 (`vs2017-win2016`)
> - Xcode 9 on macOS 10.13 (`xcode9-macos10.13`)
> - Windows Server 1803 (`win1803`)
> - Visual Studio 2015 on Windows Server 2012R2 (`vs2015-win2012r2`)

If you go to `Project Settings > Agent pools`, you will see this list instead:

> - Hosted (Hosted)
> - Hosted Linux Preview (Hosted Linux Preview)
> - Hosted macOS (Hosted macOS)
> - Hosted Ubuntu 1604 (Hosted Ubuntu 1604)
> - Hosted VS2017 (Hosted VS2017)
> - Hosted Windows Container (Hosted Windows Container)

That list seems to be missing the "Windows Server 1803" and "Visual Studio 2015" agent pools.
It has additional options for "Hosted", "Linux Preview" and "Windows Container" - but doesn't specify the "`vmAgent` string" to be used in your `azure-pipeline.yml`.

What are all the available hosted agent pools for Azure Pipelines, documented and undocumented, and their `vmImage` string to `azure-pipeline.yml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that has been mentioned in the docuemnt :

```
If your development team uses...    ...then choose this image...    ...or pool in web designer
```

For example :

"Hosted" ： `vs2015-win2012r2`

"Windows Container" ： `win1803`

[image]

Comment: Ahhhh, so e.g. `win1803` in yml is the same thing as `Hosted Windows Container` in "web designer"? So "web designer" has different names in general? ("web designer" is the web UI where you can click the pipelines together instead of using a yml file, correct?)

Comment: @janpio Yes in web designer they have different name, but using the same images ...

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Which one belongs to `Hosted Linux Preview`? That one isn't listed on this page at all.